# Create a sorted list from n sorted sublists (efficiently)

Tags: sorting, parallel-processing, raku

I was playing around with parallel sorting tonight.

```
creating sort file
naive-sort ...
1000000
23.61265496
partial-hyper-sort ...
4
7.4924575
simple-hyper-sort ...
1000000
141.7945921
naive-hyper-sort ...
1000000
23.5756172
```

Two things stand out.

a) `naive-hyper-sort` is just as fast as ordinary `sort`
b) The sorting in `partial-hyper-sort` is 66% faster than ordinary `sort`.

My problem: `partial-hyper-sort` is exactly that: "partial". It returns (on my system) 4 sublists, but you want of course one. My attempt to merge them into one (`simple-hyper-sort`) is an order of magnitude slower than the whole sorting!

So how do I get this faster? And if someone can explain why `naive-hyper-sort` is not faster than `naive-sort`, bonus points and a cookie (seriously, a literal cookie).

```
create-sortfile
    unless "tosort.txt".IO.e;

my $start = DateTime.now;
say "naive-sort ...";
say naive-sort.elems;
say DateTime.now - $start;

$start = DateTime.now;
say "partial-hyper-sort ...";
say partial-hyper-sort.elems;
say DateTime.now - $start;

$start = DateTime.now;
say "simple-hyper-sort ...";
say simple-hyper-sort.elems;
say DateTime.now - $start;


$start = DateTime.now;
say "naive-hyper-sort ...";
say naive-hyper-sort.elems;
say DateTime.now - $start;

sub create-sortfile
{
    say "creating sort file";
    my $to-sort = "tosort.txt".IO.open(:w);
    $to-sort.say( ( 10_000 .. 99_999 ).pick )
        for ( 1 .. 1_000_000  );

    $to-sort.close;
}

sub simple-hyper-sort
{
    my $to-sort = "tosort.txt".IO.open( :r );
    my $lines   = $to-sort.lines;
    my $degrees = $*KERNEL.cpu-cores;
    my $batch   = $lines.elems div $degrees;
    my @parts   = $lines.batch( $batch ).hyper( :batch(1) ).map({ .sort });
    my @index   = 0 xx $degrees;

    return gather loop
    {
        my $smallest        = Inf;
        my $smallest-index  = -1;
        my $smallest-degree = -1;

        for ^$degrees -> $degree
        {
            my $index = @index[$degree];

            if ( $index < $batch )
            {
                my $value = @parts[$degree;$index];

                if $value < $smallest
                {
                    $smallest = $value;
                    $smallest-index = $index;
                    $smallest-degree = $degree;
                }
            }
        }

        last if $smallest-index < 0;
        @index[$smallest-degree]++;
        take $smallest;
    }
}


sub partial-hyper-sort
{
    my $to-sort = "tosort.txt".IO.open( :r );
    my $lines   = $to-sort.lines;
    my $degrees = $*KERNEL.cpu-cores;
    my $batch   = $lines.elems div $degrees;
    my @parts   = $lines.batch( $batch ).hyper( :batch(1) ).map({ .sort });
}

multi sub naive-hyper-sort
{
    my $to-sort = "tosort.txt".IO.open( :r );
    my $lines   = $to-sort.lines;
    my $degrees = $*KERNEL.cpu-cores;
    my $batch   = $lines.elems div $degrees;
    $lines.hyper( :$batch, :$degrees ).sort;
}

sub naive-sort {
    my $to-sort = "tosort.txt".IO.open( :r );
    $to-sort.lines.sort;
}
```

Comment: This won't be directly helpful to you but might be indirectly by focusing potential answers... Please consider trying to: **A** [profile your code](https://docs.perl6.org/language/performance#First,_profile_your_code) and **B** produce a smaller [MRE] if you haven't considered/done those things, or, if/when you have, add a note explaining what you tried and what the results were or why you concluded they didn't/wouldn't help.

Comment: This already is an SSCE, it doesn't get any smaller. Also, no need to profile, it is clear where the bottleneck is. I could have been clearer about what I am actually asking. Late night post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `.hyper` and `.race` only results in a speedup if there is a parallel implementation of the operation that follows. At the time of writing, there is not a parallel `sort` implementation in Rakudo, which means that it will fall back to using the regular sort implementation. So, this answers why `native-hyper-sort` doesn't come out faster right now (however it almost certainly will in the future).

The idea in `simple-hyper-sort` is along the right lines: break the data up into sublists, sort the sublists, and then merge them. We can therefore parallelize the sorting of the sublists. As you've observed, this achieving a win is dependent on the merge operation itself being fast enough, and so we'd need to carefully optimize that.

It's much easier to write a tight (not to mention correct!) merge operation if it only needs to merge two sublists. Thus, we need to structure the problem in a way that gives us that. This points to a different approach:

1. Break the list in half
2. `start` a task to sort each half
3. `await` the two tasks
4. Merge the results of the two tasks

Note that step 2 involves recursion. We stop recursing when the size of a partition is too small, and use the built-in `sort` on such partitions. (We can choose to define "too small" by dividing the input list size by the number of CPU cores, along the lines of your example.)

Thus we get a solution like this:

```
sub parallel-merge-sort {
    my $to-sort = "tosort.txt".IO.open( :r );
    my $lines = $to-sort.lines;
    return do-sort $lines, ceiling($lines.elems / $*KERNEL.cpu-cores);

    sub do-sort(@in, $limit) {
        if @in.elems < $limit {
            @in.sort
        }
        else {
            my $pivot = @in.elems div 2;
            merge |await
                (start do-sort @in[0..$pivot], $limit),
                (start do-sort @in[$pivot^..@in.end], $limit)
        }
    }

    sub merge(@a, @b) {
        my @result;
        my int $a-idx = 0;
        my int $a-elems = +@a;
        my int $b-idx = 0;
        my int $b-elems = +@b;
        my int $r-idx = 0;
        while $a-idx < $a-elems && $b-idx < $b-elems {
            my $a := @a[$a-idx];
            my $b := @b[$b-idx];
            if $a before $b {
                $a-idx++;
                @result[$r-idx++] := $a;
            }
            else {
                $b-idx++;
                @result[$r-idx++] := $b;
            }
        }
        if $a-idx < $a-elems {
            @result[$r-idx++] := $_ for @a[$a-idx..*];
        }
        elsif $b-idx < $b-elems {
            @result[$r-idx++] := $_ for @b[$b-idx..*];
        }
        return @result;
    }
}
```

I didn't spend terribly long optimizing this (haven't profiled, etc.), but did take care to use natives and binding in order to reduce allocations. On My Machine, this does give a speedup over the serial sorting, however.

One other easy speedup we can get on this - at the cost of a tad more complexity in the code - comes from realizing that we don't need to slice the input in `do-sort` until the point that we actually need to send it to the built-in `sort`:

```
sub do-sort(@in, $limit, $from = 0, $to = @in.end) {
    my $elems = $to - $from;
    if $elems < $limit {
        @in[$from..$to].sort
    }
    else {
        my $pivot = $from + $elems div 2;
        merge |await
            (start do-sort @in, $limit, $from, $pivot),
            (start do-sort @in, $limit, $pivot + 1, $to)
    }
}
```

Which saves some work; by this point, I measure a factor of two speedup on the machine I'm testing it on, which isn't amazing, but given we've an enforced serial O(n) step, and a bunch more parallelized O(n) steps, over the serial sort algorithm, it's perhaps not so disappointing after all.

Comment: I need a postal address for the cookie.